# Server 18.04: netplan and link-local addressing

Tags: networking, netplan, zeroconf

I have begun experimenting with Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I ran into a problem with configuring the network. I have a PC with two network ports and one of those two ports has to get an IPv4 link-local address. In the desktop version I can achieve this by going into NetworkManager and then choose the link-local option. But with Server I have to use that new netplan program. However, the manual and other online resources make it not at all clear to me on how to achieve this. There's stuff to be found on setting up DHCP and static address but nothing on using Avahi (which Desktop uses) or other means of obtaining a 169.254.x.y address.

So: how can I write a yaml configuration that instructs netplan to set up link-local addressing on an interface?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, because currently it's not supported at all in netplan yaml; but I've filed a bug about adding support for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1771704

Comment: Thanks for filing the report. At least it's good to know that netplan has no support for this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the netplan common property for the interface:

```
link-local: [ ipv4 ]
```

However, this property doesn't exist in your version of netplan.io (0.36), it's been added to netplan.io 0.39. I get this error on ubuntu 18.04 currently:

```
unknown key link-local
```

Documentation here:
https://git.launchpad.net/netplan/tree/doc/netplan.md

You would need to obtain a more recent build of netplan.io to use this.

Comment: Setting `link-local` to only ipv4 (default was apparently ipv6) also fixed the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` startup daemon.